# How to set up an ODBC for MS Access 2016?

Tags: php, database, ms-access, odbc

I am fairly new to databases and also my English is very bad so don't mind my silly mistakes. I am using:

- MS Access 2016 to create a local database named as tc.accdb
- XAMPP to provide local host connectivity
- this php code to check whether local connectivity is achieved or not:

```html
<?php
$con = odbc_connect( "tc" , "" , "" );
if($con)
{
 echo "Connected";
}
else
{
 echo "Failed" ;
}
?>
```

But I just cannot set up Microsoft Access driver for my database. Under administrator tools >.....> System DSN, there exist Microsoft Access driver for (*.mdb) .But since I'm using Access 2016, my database has (.accdb) extension.
I've also tried saving my database as (database.mdb) to avoid extension confilicts but I've used some Office16-specific features so it can't be saved as a database with (.mdb) extension.

**Note**

Using (.mdb) connectivity with my (.accdb) database just didn't do the job  as when I try to run the check code it gives me following error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$connStr = 'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' .
            'Dbq=C:\\Users\\Igor\\Desktop\\example.accdb;';

$dbh = new PDO($connStr);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

good luck

Comment: thanks for your help but doing using above code generates this error for me :( https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzsmZaCgRWvybjk1b2RCR3M3czA

Comment: I can not open this img, could you please copy and paste error msg here?

Comment: can you tell me why you want to use access as database? why not MySql?

Comment: Just installed MS database engine. Now your code also generates the above error............ :(

Comment: And I fund access to be more user-friendly and do not m and it's limitations so using it

Comment: try to use mysql this is best solution